# Rendering multiple meshes in directx11

Tags: c++, directx11

Recently I have tried adding rendering with multiple meshes in my program. This did not go too well. The attempt I currently have goes like this

```
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(VERTEX)* nVertices.at(i);
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    bd.MiscFlags = 0;
    bd.StructureByteStride = 0;

    vertexData.pSysMem = vertices.at(i);
    vertexData.SysMemPitch = 0;
    vertexData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

    dev->CreateBuffer(&bd, &vertexData, &pVBuffer);
```

looping through the meshes and doing like wise for the index buffer. Similar to this, the render code loops through the mesh data as well:

```
        UINT stride = sizeof(VERTEX);
        UINT offset = 0;
        devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &pVBuffer, &stride, &offset);
        devcon->IASetIndexBuffer(pIBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

        devcon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

        devcon->DrawIndexed(nIndices.at(i), 0, 0);
```

But all of this only ends up rendering one of the meshes. Does anyone know what I need to change to fix this or whether I need to have a completely different approach? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be calling create once per mesh, then draw once per mesh per frame.  If you're really only storing the created buffer in the single `pVBuffer` object, you'll only have access to one for drawing.  What does the code between your two posted segments look like?

Comment: There's nothing in between really however I guess this might interest you: for (int i = 0; i < modelCount; i++), std::vector<VERTEX*> vertices and std::vector<DWORD*> indices.

Comment: Should also mention that was basically saying that it loops the creation and render for each mesh data set.

Comment: @MooseBoys w/r/t "You should be calling create once per mesh..." While I don't know much about DX, in GL best practice is to use the same buffer as many meshes as possible, as long as they have the same vertex format and usage (ie. don't put static meshes in the same buffer with dynamically updated or streamed meshes, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, the only problem now is knowing how to put them in the buffers.

Comment: You need to give a more complete example of your entire per-frame graphics code with screen output. There's a few fundamental issues here.

Comment: Here is a copy of the project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B31ZpbBZ5QAMbGV6eHR4VmxUcFU/edit?usp=sharing It uses the fbx sdk, diectx and mfc. The files with the code are model and MFCApplication32View.

Comment: Since you are using ``D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT`` this buffer is intended for 'static' usage. If you are doing dynamic submission, you would use ``D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC`` and then you could use Map/Unmap. See the PrimitiveBatch class in the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929).

Comment: So would this involve calling memcpy again repeatedly?
 
    devcon->Map(pIBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &ms);    
    memcpy(ms.pData, OurIndices, sizeof(OurIndices));                   
    devcon->Unmap(pIBuffer, NULL);

Answer (score 1):

ok im not a c++ developer but i do this all the time in c#.

Essentially you need to wrap up a vbo and a ibo in to some container like this ...

```
class Mesh {
   public VertexBuffer Vertices;
   public IndexBuffer  Indices;
}
```

Then run your code generate a bunch of mesh objects ...

```
List<Mesh> Meshes = GetMeLotsOfMeshes();
```

Then you do something like ...

Apply Shader state to context
foreach mesh {
   Set vert and index buffer 
   call draw indexed
}

My c# code for this works something like this ...

I have a material class which basically wraps up the creation and management of a shader stack in which i do something like this once before i begin dealing with any meshes ...

```
public void Apply(DeviceContext context, Matrix world)
{
    if (LastMaterial == null || LastMaterial != ClassName)
    {
        //apply material and buffers to device context
        context.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = Topology;
        context.InputAssembler.InputLayout = layout;
        context.VertexShader.Set(vertexShader);
        context.PixelShader.Set(pixelShader);
        if (sampler != null) context.PixelShader.SetSampler(0, sampler);
        LastMaterial = ClassName;
    }
    ApplyConstants(context, world);
}
```

After thats been done once I begin looping through my meshes first i apply the shader constants for the buffers im about to render (world matrix for the object) then I go in to the mesh class and call draw which sets the right buffers and then calls draw on them ...

```
protected override void ApplyConstants(DeviceContext context, Matrix world)
{
    context.PixelShader.SetShaderResource(0, textureView);
    wvp = world * camera.ViewProjection;
    wvp.Transpose();
    context.VertexShader.SetConstantBuffer(0, constantBuffer);
    context.UpdateSubresource(ref wvp, constantBuffer);
}

public void DrawTo(DeviceContext context)
{
    context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(VertexBuffer, Utilities.SizeOf<T>(), 0));
    context.InputAssembler.SetIndexBuffer(IndexBuffer, Format.R32_UInt, 0);
    context.DrawIndexed(Indices.Count, 0, 0);
}
```